# php modbus over tcp ( device gateway)

Tags: php, tcp, modbus

I need library php for Read data Modbus Over Tcp gateway .

$modbus = new ModbusMaster('192.168.0.15', "UDP");

```
$recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(0, '19012', 2);
```

if i change 0 per ID slave it is not working
please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your gateway a simple TCP to serial port converter or is it a specialized Modbus RTU(serial) to Modbus TCP gateway converter?

The first will not work,  a Modbus RTU slave doesn't understand Modbus TCP protocol byte sequence, both are different protocols

Why you configure the master as UDP if you are using a TCP gateway ?

Comment: No my gateway is prodata (datalogger)